# How to dynamically add new li tags to an unordered list

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a list that will contain my videos. I tried my best but it is not working. Below is my code.

Is there any problem in my code?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="generateList();">Click on me</button>
  <script>
    function generateList() {
      var listItems = [{
        filename: "Besabriyaan",
        path: "videos/Besabriyaan.mp4"
      }, {
        filename: "Parwah nahin",
        path: "videos/Parwah nahin.mp4"
      }, {
        filename: "Laila main laila",
        path: "videos/Laila main laila.mp4"
      }, {
        filename: "Kaabil trailer",
        path: "videos/Kaabil trailer.mp4"
      }];
      var list = document.createElement("ul");
      list.setAttribute("id", "song lists");
      document.body.appendChild(list);
      for (i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
        var li[i] = document.createElement("li");
        var a[i] = document.createElement("a");
        a[i].setAttribute("id", listItems.length + 1);
        a[i].setAttribute("href", listItems[i].path);
        var filename[i] = document.createTextNode(listItem[i].filename);
        a[i].appendChild(filename[i]);
        li[i].appendChild(a[i]);
        list.appendChild(li[i]);
      }
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: He meant: Do what I just did for you. Next time click the `<>` in the editor and paste the html, javascript and css into the correct boxes, then click TIDY to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few issues in you code.

1. Variables declared inside loop are declared with a index which is not correct and throwing error. Declare you variable like **var li, var a** , these variables will be overwritten in the next iterations.
2. There is no listItem object in your code it is listItems

```js
function generateList() {
  var listItems = [{
    filename: "Besabriyaan",
    path: "videos/Besabriyaan.mp4"
  }, {
    filename: "Parwah nahin",
    path: "videos/Parwah nahin.mp4"
  }, {
    filename: "Laila main laila",
    path: "videos/Laila main laila.mp4"
  }, {
    filename: "Kaabil trailer",
    path: "videos/Kaabil trailer.mp4"
  }];
  var list = document.createElement("ul");
  list.setAttribute("id", "song lists");
  document.body.appendChild(list);
  var li, a, filename;
  for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {

    li = document.createElement("li");
    a = document.createElement("a");
    a.setAttribute("id", "movie_" +i);
    a.setAttribute("href", listItems[i].path);
    filename = document.createTextNode(listItems[i].filename);
    a.appendChild(filename);
    li.appendChild(a);
    list.appendChild(li);

  }
};
```

```html
<button onclick="generateList();">Click on me</button>
```

Comment: You are right. I had made a big mistake. Sorry small mistake. Thanks for helping me

Comment: i suggest to move the declaration of variables outside of the loop to the top of the function, even count variables like `i`, which is not declared here.

Comment: @user6542894 made an edit to get rid of duplicate ids for anchor element. which was due to a.setAttribute("id", listItems.length + 1);